# Listing drivers in ring0/kernel?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, kernel, driver

Just a question, I'm wondering if it's possible to hook in to Ring0/Kernel to display the list of loaded drivers running within the kernel? Would I need to write a driver to do so?

Similar to how you can list all the running processes quite easily.

Oh and this is in C++ / Windows.

Comment: Try lsmod command with system() procedure.

Comment: there's a command for that, if I'm not mistaken, `drivers`, but I'm not sure whether it's the command since it has been a long time I don't open a Windows box for that.

Comment: I.e. what OS are we talking about? And why don't you ask the OS directly?

Comment: I suppose it's Windows - since the question is tagged with Visual C++.

Comment: oh, the command I was talking about is `driverquery`: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/generate-a-list-of-installed-drivers-from-the-command-line/

Comment: @bkausbk Please don't. Don't *ever* use `system()` for *anything* - it's a security nightmare and should *never* be used.

Answer (score 5):

As I've commented, use the `driverquery` command.

```
driverquery
Display a list of all installed device drivers and their properties.

Syntax

driverquery  [/s Computer] [/u Domain\User /p Password]
         [/fo {TABLE|LIST|CSV}] [/nh] [/v] [/si]
example

Show all installed device drivers in Table output:
driverquery

Show all installed device drivers in a CSV format:
DriverQuery /fo csv

Without a header:
DriverQuery /nh

Drivers that are not signed:
DriverQuery /si | findstr FALSE

Find drivers that are currently Running:
Driverquery.exe /v |findstr Running

Show installed device drivers on a remote machine
driverquery /s ipaddress

Show installed device drivers on server64 and authenticate as a different user:
driverquery /s server64 /u ss64Ddom\user123 /p p@sswor3d /fo list

Export a verbose listing of drivers to a file
driverquery /v /fo csv > T:\driverlist.csv

When running DriverQuery within PowerShell, the CSV output format can be used to turn the output into objects. The PowerShell function below turns DriverQuery into a graphical tool that will list drivers from both local and remote systems (assuming you have the appropriate permissions.)

function Show-DriverDialog {
    param(
        $ComputerName = $env:computername
    )

    driverquery.exe /S $ComputerName /FO CSV  | 
      ConvertFrom-Csv | 
      Out-GridView -Title "Driver on \\$ComputerName"
```

Source: http://windows.commands.com/driverquery

Special attention to:

```
Find drivers that are currently Running:
Driverquery.exe /v | findstr Running
```

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY want to write your own code for this, then here's a ["Device Driver Information"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page on Microsfts website.

From that, you should be able to pull together the pieces (it's pretty similar to listing the currently running processes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command sc

```
sc query type driver
```

This will provide you a textual list of currently running drivers.
You can play around with flags like running/stopped.
From there it's a short batch/bash/python command to get just the service names.

Comment: 2021 update: I had to use it like this to get it to work: `sc query type= driver`

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to write a driver to list all running drivers in Windows kernel, however it requires some dirty hacks to call undocumented kernel functions. First you have to declare 3 kernel functions:

```
#include <ntddk.h>

NTKERNELAPI
NTSTATUS
ObReferenceObjectByName(
    PUNICODE_STRING ObjectPath,
    ULONG Attributes,
    PACCESS_STATE AccessState,
    ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    POBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,
    KPROCESSOR_MODE AccessMode,
    PVOID ParseContext,
    PVOID* ObjectPtr
);

NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
ZwQueryDirectoryObject(
    HANDLE DirectoryHandle,
    PVOID Buffer,
    ULONG Length,
    BOOLEAN ReturnSingleEntry,
    BOOLEAN RestartScan,
    PULONG Context,
    PULONG ReturnLength
);

NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
ZwOpenDirectoryObject(
    PHANDLE DirectoryHandle,
    ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes
);
```

Then, you can enumerate all kernel objects in the `\\Driver\\` namespace, which are loaded drivers:

```
NTSTATUS EnumerateDriversInDriverNamespace()
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    HANDLE directoryHandle;
    UNICODE_STRING directoryName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objectAttributes;
    ULONG context = 0;
    ULONG returnLength;
    POBJECT_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION objinf;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&directoryName, L"\\Driver");
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&objectAttributes, &directoryName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, NULL);

    status = ZwOpenDirectoryObject(&directoryHandle, DIRECTORY_QUERY, &objectAttributes);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Failed to open \\Driver namespace: 0x%x\n", status);
        return status;
    }

    while (TRUE) {
        status = ZwQueryDirectoryObject(directoryHandle, NULL, 0, TRUE, FALSE, &context, &returnLength);
        if (status != STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL)
            break;

        objinf = ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, returnLength);
        if (!objinf) {
            ZwClose(directoryHandle);
            DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Failed to allocate in paged pool\n");
            return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
        }

        status = ZwQueryDirectoryObject(directoryHandle, objinf, returnLength, TRUE, FALSE, &context, &returnLength);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            if (status == STATUS_NO_MORE_ENTRIES) {
                DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "No more entries :(\n");
                status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
            }
            else {
                DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Failed to query directory object: 0x%x\n", status);
            }
            break;
        }
        
        PUNICODE_STRING dName = (PUNICODE_STRING)&objinf->Name;
        // dName here is the name of the driver
        ExFreePool(objinf);
    }

    ZwClose(directoryHandle);

    return status;
}
```